# How to configure low-level socket properties for a web server (Tomcat) embedded in my spring-boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

How can I configure low-level options for spring-boot embedded web server (in my concrete case I am using Tomcat)?

As an example, I would like set `SO_REUSEADDR` to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is Tomcat-specific**

Turns out this is possible through [TomcatConnectorCustomizer](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.5.12/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatConnectorCustomizer.html) beans, e.g.

```
@Bean
public TomcatConnectorCustomizer tomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
    return connector -> connector.setProperty("socket.soReuseAddress", "true");
}
```

---

How does it work?

`connector.setProperty` is implemented with `IntrospectionUtils.setProperty` which looks for bean property with a matching name, and failing that, [uses a `getProperty` method](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/IntrospectionUtils.java#L166) in the connector's `ProtocolHandler`.

In my case, the ProtocolHandler was `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol` which has a [setProperty](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProtocol.java#L120) in its superclass `org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol`, that in the end invokes `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint`'s [setProperty](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.java#L865).

That method then [differentiates](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.63/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.java#L924) properties with `socket.` prefix, and again reflectively matches it to `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties` accessors (in our case [setSoReuseAddress](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.63/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketProperties.java#L388)).

In the end, when the sockets get created, [the stored configuration is used](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.63/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketProperties.java#L215) when configuring a new socket.

---

It should be also noted (again, this is Tomcat specific) that Tomcat also uses JVM defaults ([link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketProperties.html#soReuseAddress)).